# Saving a default value in a Django form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django template where i'm using two different forms:

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = TradingForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Success")


    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = MyForm()


    context = {

        'first_form': FirstForm(request.POST or None),
        'second_form': SecondForm(request.POST or None),
    }

    return render(request, "main/template.html", context)
```

**form.py**

```
  class FirstForm(forms.ModelForm):

        rate = forms.CharField()
        amount = forms.FloatField()


        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ("rate", "amount")

        def save(self, commit=True):
            send = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
            if commit:
                send.save()
            return send


  class SecondForm(forms.ModelForm):

        rate = forms.CharField()
        amount = forms.FloatField()


        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ("firstfield", "secondfield")

        def save(self, commit=True):
            send = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
            if commit:
                send.save()
            return send
```

As you can see, those two forms are using the same model, but they have different fields, so the user will submit those fields and the data will be saved in my DB:

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    formtype = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self): # ALL the signature

        super(Trade, self).save()
```

The user submits the fields `amount` and `rate`. The field `user` it's not submitted by the user, but it's saved by Django. There is a fourth field, the `formtype` field. This field must not be submitted by the user, but 'automatically', just like the field `user` is saved.

An example: if the user used the first form, in my DB, below the `formtype` column i should see `FirstForm`, same if the user submitted the data from the second form. I don't know if what i'm trying to accomplish is clear, but i wanted to know how to accomplish this in Django, if there is a way. Every advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already overriding `save` you can add it to the model instance there:

```
   class FirstForm(forms.ModelForm):
        ...
        def save(self, commit=True):
            send = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
            send.formtype = 'FirstForm'
            if commit:
                send.save()
            return send
```

Comment: This works! Is it safe though? Isn't there any way for someone to alter the DOM or send a POST request with a third party tool?

Comment: You could write a test to check, but I believe any values not defined in your form's `fields` Meta class will be ignored even if keys that match the model's fields are included in request.POST. Plus you're setting the value immediately before calling `save` which would overwrite any existing property on the `send` instance anyways.